# How do I setup an automatic backup for api.ai bot?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

I want my bot to be automatically backed up every time I make a change or on a regular base. Is there a way to implement this

Comment: You're looking for source control.

Comment: I am sorry but that does not satisfy my need. If you think it does could you please elaborate

Comment: Your need is incredibly unclear.

Comment: I want my bot to be automatically backed up in my repository every time I make a change or on a regular base. Is there a way to implement this

Comment: That's exactly what source control does.

Answer (score 0):

No, API.AI doesn't have a backup `GET` request. So you cannot automatically backup your bot.
But, if you want to backup your **Entities** and **Intents** , which are the main contents on the bot, you can use `GET` requests to automatically download the Intents and Entities. You can find how to do it [here](https://docs.api.ai/docs/intents) and [here](https://docs.api.ai/docs/entities) respectively. But keep in mind there is a limit on the number of Intents and Entities you can download with a single `GET` request, so keep that in mind.